# Passing DateTime as a parameter

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, powershell-3.0

I've read widely that I can pass in an argument to my powershell script via:

```
param (
    [Datetime]$argument
)
```

I've also read that I can define a default value:

```
param (
    [Datetime]$argument = Get-Date "5/1/2006 7:00 AM"
)
```

However on doing this I get:

> At C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\Scripts\ScrumTimer.ps1:2 char:26
>   +     [Datetime]$argument = Get-Date "5/1/2006 7:00 AM"
>   +                          ~ Missing expression after '='. At C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\Scripts\ScrumTimer.ps1:2 char:24
>   +     [Datetime]$argument = Get-Date "5/1/2006 7:00 AM"
>   +                        ~ Missing ')' in function parameter list. At C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\Scripts\ScrumTimer.ps1:3 char:1
>   + )
>   + ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

This only appears to occur for `DateTime`, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try enclose value in `()`

```
param (
    [Datetime]$argument = (Get-Date "5/1/2006 7:00 AM")
)
```

Comment: You legend - thank you.  I suppose it makes sense that it says there's a missing expression.  Is there any reason why we have to do this?

Comment: The reason is in how powershell engine parse the script: the `()` force the parser to resolve the `get-date` value before assign it to the variable.